# calculate last date, given start date and month PHP

Tags: php

There is a start date(let it be 16/02/2016) and months(let it be 3 months) given to me.
how do I calculate the end date?

Comment: can you state your code and show how far you have tried?

Comment: Post your attempts what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
$myDate = "16-02-2016";
$final_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months", strtotime($myDate)));
```

Comment: It results into `1970-04-01`

Comment: But why adding 3 months results in the year 1970?

Comment: Its because your date format is in American Format i.e. `mm/dd/yyyy` you need to first convert your date into European date format i.e. `dd-mm-yyyy` so your date must be like as `$myDate = str_replace("/","-","16/02/2016");` and then the above code is ready to go @PhoEnix

Comment: Uchiha is right.. 
But It will work if you use m/d/Y format but it will not work with d/m/Y

Comment: I'm not getting the result. Also I have to add dynamic months.So is the following code right?
$FromDate= str_replace("/","-",$FromDate);
$ToDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$durationTo, strtotime($FromDate)));

Comment: The problem with this code if ever you have a date of "2016-01-31" you will get an output of "2016-05-01"

Comment: So how is it wrong? You want 2016-04-31?

Comment: The proper result maybe for after 3 months date will be the last day of the month "2016-04-30" instead getting the 1st day of the next month "2016-05-01" prior on counting by month not the 30 days. If he wanted to produce the per month not skipping a month if the date falls off the range of the days of that month

Comment: example maybe demonstrated as per month `2016-01-31`, `2016-02-29`, `2016-03-31`, `2016-04-30`. If he wanted it to be like this. Just saying.